# Обращение к объектам обнаружения LLD Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, мониторинг

Имеется LLD правило для обнаружения устройств с ключем **rPDU2DeviceConfigLocation**, в этом же правиле есть прототипы элементов данных с ключем вида **rPDU2DeviceStatusPower.[{#SNMPINDEX}]**.
Мне необходимо создать вычисляемый элемент данных в родительском шаблоне с использованием данных, получаемых обнаружением.
Вопрос: как обратиться к данным из обнаружения при создании элемента данных в шаблоне?
*Zabbix 4.4*

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался: last(rPDU2DeviceStatusPower.[1]), без доп. ссылок, значение host добавляется автоматически в рамках одного хоста